# How can I print formatted multiple values from a matrix using jinja2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I've been trying to create a template using jinja2, but I can't get to print multiple values from a matrix in a formatted way. What I mean is, say I have the following matrix:

```
test = [[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0]]
```

What I'd like to do is to print these values in a file like this:

```
   1.0000000000000000E+00   0.0000000000000000E+00   0.0000000000000000E+00
   0.0000000000000000E+00   1.0000000000000000E+00   0.0000000000000000E+00
```

I've tried the following:

```
{% for row in test -%}
{% for i in zip(*[iter(row)]*3) -%}
{{ '{:>25.16E}{:>25.16E}{:>25.16E}'.format(*i) }}
{% endfor -%}
{% endfor -%}
```

But this raises the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'iter' is undefined
```

So apparently I can't use iter() with jinja2. Any ideas on how to achieve it otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @CodeLikeBeaker correctly points out ways to add `iter` to the Jinja environment, the simpler thing to do would be to just splat `row` into `.format` without the nested loop (since the inner loop is a single entry anyway):

```
{% for row in test -%}
{{ '{:>25.16E}{:>25.16E}{:>25.16E}'.format(*row) }}
{% endfor -%}
```

Comment: Very good point as well. This is indeed the much simpler solution

Answer (score 2):

Jinja2 does not support the iter() or zip() functions by default. However, you can configure the flask jinja environment to use those functions (as long as you're using flask):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.globals.update(zip=zip, iter=iter)
```

Once you do that, you will be golden. If you are not using flask, check the documentation of the framework you're using to see how to configure the jinja environment.

You can also update jinja2 Environment directly. But make sure you load your template using the env variable:

```
import jinja2
env = jinja2.Environment()
env.globals.update(zip=zip, iter=iter)
```